# Error: Expected undefined to be a GraphQL schema on hello world

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

Below is my simple graph ql hellow rold code which i directly used from graphql official docs toget started, somehow its giving me error: Expected undefined to be a GraphQL schema on hello world

```
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

var root = { hello: () => "Hello world!" };

graphql(schema, "{ hello }", root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Here is the link for the correct code: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/

Answer (score 2):

Seems the documentation is wrong. It needs to be updated, Can you try updating the code like below?

**From**

```
graphql(schema, "{ hello }", root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**To**

```
graphql({
    schema: schema, 
    source: '{ hello }', 
    rootValue: root
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```